# Accessing raw data (PPG) from heart rate sensor in smart watch

Tags: sensors, samsung-galaxy-gear

Recently I learned that the raw data from the heart rate optical sensor (what is called PPG signal) is available for Galaxy S5 devices using the new sensor extension SDK from Samsung, which means that the sensor physically outputs this data. 
Since the same sensor is used in Gear watches, I'm wondering if there is any way to access this raw data from the watch's sensor.
I reviewed the Samsung developers site and different forums, but didn't find the way to do it, only to access the heart rate itself.
Will appreciate your advises.